# Java incompatible types for inherited classes

Tags: java, oop

I'm pretty new to Java, assume these types of questions have been asked before, but after a few hours of search still didn't find the solution for this.

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class DBQueryResponse {...}
```

And two classes inheriting it

```
public class TransactionKeyResult extends DBQueryResponse {...}
public class SalespersonIdResult extends DBQueryResponse {...}
```

In another class, I have this function

```
private DynamoDBQueryExpression<? extends DBQueryResponse> generateQueryExpression() {...}
```

But whenever I tried to call it somewhere else as such:

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<SalespersonIdResult> queryExpression = generateQueryExpression();
DynamoDBQueryExpression<TransactionKeyResult> queryExpression = generateQueryExpression();
```

It always complains about "Incompatible types", which it expects DBQueryResponse but found else. I always assumed due to polymorphism this is allowed.

The reason I had to use 2 classes is that they are making similar calls to different aws database.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try using a generic Template to handle the different object instances.

Check this out: https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics, it might help.

Comment: If you absolutely need to keep the wildcard instead of using generics, you can change the type of the variables to get something like `DynamoDBQueryExpression<? extends DBQueryResponse> queryExpression`

Comment: If you have two identical calls to the same method back to back, why do they expect different types in their results?

Comment: @Thomas it's using AWS mapper calls, so although they go through the same set of queries, the results will be different, the tables they point to are declared within their own classes too

Comment: To clarify, there are two separate implementations of `generateQueryExpression` or does the one implementation return different types depending on some internal condition?

Comment: @Thomas It's the latter condition, one implementation but return type differs by internal condition. Sorry for not being clear earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method should return an exact type rather than wildcard, but the type can be bound:

```java
<T extends DBQueryResponse> DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> generateQueryExpression()
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like generics was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler thinks this is dangerous.Method returns an indeterminate type. Assigning it to a certain type is a sure way to fail compilation.You can continue to use wildcards:

```
    DynamoDBQueryExpression<? extends DBQueryResponse> queryExpression = generateQueryExpression();
    DynamoDBQueryExpression<? extends DBQueryResponse> queryExpression = generateQueryExpression();
```

Answer (score 1):

The casting isn't allowed because you're trying to cast from general to specific.  Let's say I have two classes B and C that extend a common class A and a method that returns a list of A(or something that extends A).

```
List<A> foo = method ();
```

Is valid because no matter if the implementation of method returns B or C, they both extend A.  Now for the one more similar to your example.

```
List<B> baz = method ();
```

This is not valid because method's return type is A.  Even if you know the implementation will return B.  As far as the compiler knows it could also return C or any other child of A that can't be cast to B.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for the lesson. Converting from JS to Java always gets me.